# Linking a CSS image URL in laravel

Tags: css, laravel

I want to add a background-image with a laravel URL. I can do this by just including the web path itself but I would like to use Laravel URL.

Here is how I do it now:

```
.mystyle{
background-image: url("www.myproject.com/assets/img/background.png")
}
```

Here is how I want it:

```
.mystyle{
background-image: url("{{ URL::asset('assets/img/background.png }}") 
}
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can even use it like this:

```
.mystyle{
    background-image: url("/assets/img/background.png") 
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. the key is the difference between url('assets/img') and url('/assets/img'), the second one looks from the root of the domain, not from the current url.

Answer (score 19):

Put your image into `public/assets/img` directory and use the [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset) helper:

```
.mystyle{
    background-image: url("{{ asset('assets/img/background.png') }}") 
}
```

Comment: But you can't use the `asset()` helper in .scss or .css files?

Answer (score 12):

I have used inline css for a class and this is what actually worked in my case

```
  style=" background-image: url('{{asset('images/cover.jpg')}}');"
```

Answer (score 8):

This absolutely work

```
.mystyle {
     background-image: url("../assets/img/background.png") 
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If assets is a folder in your public directory then you can write like that

```
style="background-image: url({{asset('assets/img/background.png')}})"
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using new version of Laravel then follow below.

public/img/test.png
if your image exists in the public root dir of the application then you don't need to specify public, you need to put **../** to go one step back and find the image.

```
background-image: url('../img/test.png');
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way . Transfer the contents of the css file to blade php file. Then use

```
background-image: url({{asset('assets/img/background.png')}})"
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that works for me:
url("../images/formIcons/seeingEye96.png");

Comment: This is basically the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54134504/2227743).

Answer (score 0):

in the backgroundi-image add

background-image: url({{asset('assets/img/background.png')}})"

hope after doing this you find the  output

Answer (score 0):

This is correct answer - background-image: url('../img/background.png');
As assest will not be work. its 100% work. must try.

Answer (score 0):

```
 
class ImageUrlController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke($path_file)//: object
    {
        if(Storage::exists('/public/images/'.$path_file)){
            $image_path=response()->file(Storage::path('/public/images/'.$path_file));
        }else {
            $image_path=response()->file(Storage::path('/public/images/default.jpg'));
        }

        return $image_path;
    }
}
```

in more detail [Laravel image url](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-s1a6yFyy4&t=184s)